# Replacing fragment from fragment causes Fragments content to overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a ListView inside a fragment. When i click an item on the List i want to "start" a new fragment using replace. This is the result. I was supposed to get only the **BUTTON**:

[image]

This is inside **onItemClick:**

```
Fragment nextFrag= new VitaminFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(vitamin_fragment.getId(), nextFrag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**Inside VitaminFragment's onCreateView:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("created", "vitamin_fragment_2");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.supplement_properties_layout, container, false);
}
```

and VitaminFragment XML (supplement_properties_layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/supplements_properties_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**VitaminWiki's layout is created programatically:**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View result = initComponents();
       .....
       .....
}


   private RelativeLayout initComponents() {

        vitamin_fragment = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        vitamin_fragment.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_57 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        vitamin_fragment.setLayoutParams(layout_57);

        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        ......
        vitamin_fragment.addView(listView);

        com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip p = new PagerSlidingTabStrip(getActivity());
        ...........
        p.setLayoutParams(params);
        vitamin_fragment.addView(p);

        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
        .........
        vitamin_fragment.addView(viewPager);

        return vitamin_fragment;
    }
```

Finally [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15854314/DashboardActivity.java) is the Activity that fragments are attached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replace() method from FragmentTransaction simply removes all fragment from the specified container and then call add(). So if the specified container is empty, replace() simply adds a fragment on top of the current view.

You should post the XML file for your VitaminFragment, but I'd say add a background to your VitaminFragment and you should be fine.

And don't forget to make the main layout of your fragment clickable. Otherwise any click on something else than the button will go through the Fragment and probably click on an item on you ListView.

Your Fragment should look something like this :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true" >
```

EDIT : If you want the replace() method to work and actually remove the ListView from the activity, make sure you call it on the same container that you used to add the first fragment in the first place. Also, the first Fragment needs to have been added dynamically. When I say added dynamically, I mean using the FragmentTransaction.add() method.

Comment: I don't get it. Which one is the new Fragment that you want to add on top of the ListView ? Cause the code you submitted seems to be for a fragment with a ListView in it and I don't see any Button. So I'm not sure i'm looking at the right thing.

Comment: VitaminFragment i want to add on top of the list view. Check my edit

Comment: Ok so my answer stands. Change the XML file you just posted (for the supplement_property_layout) adding a background of your choice and making it clickable.

Comment: What if i want to keep activity's background? any idea?

Comment: Why replace does not remove old fragment? I do not like the background hack

Comment: Sure you either add the same background in your XML as in you activity, or you can remove the ListView before adding the new fragment and you keep the new fragment transparent (no background)

Comment: Removing the list is not a good idea because i implement onBackPressed mechanism. Do you have any idea why replace() function does not work properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71542/discussion-between-jdenais-and-john).